# Problems while using ANT for creating HTML (junit style) report

Tags: file, ant, build, jmeter

I am trying to generate an HTML/Junit Style report for the jMeter tests by using ANT. I have created a build file for this and have done all the pre-requisites like:
set the required variables like java home, ant home, path variables; put the ant build file and the required .jmx file (for jmeter execution) in a folder and calling "ant" command pointing at the same folder.
I tried calling the ant build file by giving commands as *ant* and *ant -Dtest="Sample Workload Script"*.

The issue i get is that when i run this commands it reaches to the point of executing the test plan and then gives a java platform error (as shown in attached image) and stops the build. Any pointers to what might be causing this?

[Java Platform Error when running the ANT Build file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VpZN.jpg)

I read somewhere that the ANT version may not be compatible with java 1.8. Speaking of which i am using Ant 1.9.7 and java 1.8.73

My build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<project name="ant-jmeter" default="all">
    <description>

        Sample build file for use with ant-jmeter.jar
        See http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

    To run a test and create the output report:
        ant -Dtest=script

    To run a test only:
        ant -Dtest=script run

    To run report on existing test output
        ant -Dtest=script report

    The "script" parameter is the name of the script without the .jmx suffix.

    Additional options:
        -Dshow-data=y - include response data in Failure Details
        -Dtestpath=xyz - path to test file(s) (default user.dir).
                         N.B. Ant interprets relative paths against the build file
        -Djmeter.home=.. - path to JMeter home directory (defaults to parent of this build file)
        -Dreport.title="My Report" - title for html report (default is 'Load Test Results')

        Deprecated:
        -Dformat=2.0 - use version 2.0 JTL files rather than 2.1

    </description>

    <property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>                 <!--<property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>-->
    <property name="jmeter.home" value="C:\apache-jmeter-3.0"/>
    <property name="report.title" value="Load Test Results"/>

    <!-- Name of test (without .jmx) -->
    <property name="test" value="Test"/>

    <!-- Should report include response data for failures? -->
    <property name="show-data" value="n"/>

    <property name="format" value="2.1"/>

    <condition property="style_version" value="">
        <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.0"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="style_version" value="_21">
        <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.1"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="funcMode">
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="funcMode" value="false">
      <not>
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
      </not>
    </condition>

    <!-- Allow jar to be picked up locally -->
    <path id="jmeter.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="ant-jmeter*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef
        name="jmeter"
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>
    <!--classpathref="jmeter.classpath"-->
    <!--classpathref="C:\apache-jmeter-3.0\extras"-->

    <target name="all" depends="run,report"/>

    <target name="run">
        <echo>funcMode = ${funcMode}</echo>
        <delete file="${testpath}/${test}.html"/>
        <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
            testplan ="${basedir}/${test}.jmx"          
            resultlog="${basedir}/${test}.jtl">
        <!--
            <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
            <jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>
        -->
            <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
            <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
        </jmeter>
    </target>

    <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="report" depends="xslt-report,copy-images">
        <echo>Report generated at ${report.datestamp}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
        <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
        <xslt
            classpathref="xslt.classpath"
            force="true"
            in="${basedir}/${test}.jtl"
            out="${basedir}/${test}.html"
            style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report${style_version}.xsl">
            <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
            <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
            <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <!-- Copy report images if needed -->
    <target name="copy-images" depends="verify-images" unless="samepath">
        <copy file="${basedir}/expand.png" tofile="${testpath}/expand.png"/>
        <copy file="${basedir}/collapse.png" tofile="${testpath}/collapse.png"/>
    </target>

    <target name="verify-images">
        <condition property="samepath">
                <equals arg1="${testpath}" arg2="${basedir}" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <!-- Check that the xalan libraries are present -->
    <condition property="xalan.present">
          <and>
              <!-- No need to check all jars; just check a few -->
            <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler"/>
          </and>
    </condition>

    <target name="_message_xalan" unless="xalan.present">
          <echo>Cannot find all xalan and/or serialiser jars</echo>
        <echo>The XSLT formatting may not work correctly.</echo>
        <echo>Check you have xalan and serializer jars in ${lib.dir}</echo>
    </target>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update "jmeter" section of your `build.xml` file as follows:

```
<jmeter
    jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
    testplan ="${basedir}/${test}.jmx"          
    resultlog="${basedir}/${test}.jtl"
    jmeterlogfile="${basedir}/jmeter.log"> <!-- add this line to enabled logging-->
```

Re-run your test and look into *jmeter.log* file under your `C:\workspace\CPT` folder - it should contain enough troubleshooting information so you will be able to find out the cause. If you have problems interpreting the log file - add it to your question.

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: I added the line and ran it. It does not give any jmeter.log file at the base directory.

Comment: By the way, there is an ambiguity while i check the java version.

Comment: When i do **java -version**, it shows `java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)`. When i do **javac -version**, it shows `javac 1.8.0_60`. Can this be the core issue?